# Is it possible to recover deleted column data in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

If we have deleted some(20 query) data in Cassandra using below delete query.
DELETE lastname FROM cycling.cyclist_name WHERE id = c7fceba0-c141-4207-9494-a29f9809de6f;

So how we can restore/find above deleted data in Cassandra? please help

Answer (score 2):

If no compaction happened yet, then you may recover the data from SSTables via `sstabledump` and get them from generated JSON files.

But correct answer is to use some kind of backup solution - via OpsCenter, or using the manual backup via `nodetool snapshot`, etc. More information you can find in [following article](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001593706-Manual-Backup-and-Restore-with-Point-in-time-and-table-level-restore-) of DataStax support team.

Comment: From sstabledump you means to extract the data and insert it again right? How from Opscenter?

Comment: yes - reinsert them. From OpsCenter - you simply restore from previous snapshots - but then you may lose some changes made in other places.

Comment: Okay Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra doesn't delete data immediately. As Alex hinted, it will still be in the sstables (data files) until compaction, and only marked with a deletion flag (tombstoned).

You can dump the contents of the sstables into text files and then search for your id.

Do something like this for each sstable:

```
sstabledump mc-3-big-Data.db > dump2019a
```

These text files will have your data, with a "deletion_info" flag. You can then search for your id and retrieve the data.

You should act quickly before compaction, though.

Comment: Okay Thanks, but above helpful if we act before compaction but if we will know the issue after compaction then ?